# How to replace <li> tag with break

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have a string of following form

```
<li>Hello</li>
<li>How are you?</li>
```

I want to replace it with

```
Hello<br>
How are you?<br>
```

Is it possible through preg_replace or any other method?

Comment: Have you tried something ?

Comment: Yes this can be done in many ways. I think of a simple way using str_replace().

Comment: `str_replace(array('<li>','</li>'), array('','<br>'), '<li>Hello</li><li>How are you?</li>');`

Comment: my problem is above code will work only if li tag is empty but li may contain style attribute, how to handle this case with preg_replace, I am badly stuck